# Subsets vs Subspaces of a Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The definition of a Subspace of a Vector Space is usually given by:

> Suppose $V$ is a Vector Space over a field $\mathbb F$.
>
> A subset $W$ of $V$ is a Subspace of $V$ if and only if $W$ is also a Vector Space over $\mathbb F$ under the addition and scalar multiplication operations defined on $V$.

I apologize for this rather pedantic question, but I'm just curious.

When we say "$W$ is a subset of a Vector Space $V$" do we mean that $W$ is also equipped with some binary operations (i.e. is it equipped with the same binary operations that are defined on $V$$)?$
For otherwise, doesn't this mean that a Subspace is not really a Vector Space since Vector Spaces are sets that are equipped with addition and scalar multiplication operations while, in this case, a Subspace is not.

Comment: We mean $W$ is a subset of the underlying set of $V$, paired with the restrictions of the operations from $V$, under which it satisfies the axioms of a vector space.

Comment: It is a common [abuse of language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_notation#Abuse_of_language) in mathematics not to distinguish between a structured object and the underlying set

Comment: Thank you very much J.W.Tanner & blargoner . Just needed a confirmation on this.